# CASESAFEID(lookupId) not returning 18char id in Lightning Email Template

Tags: lightning, email-template, formula-field

I have a Lightning Email Template in which I'm using merge fields of an object, where one of them is a lookup record id (Application__c), and need the 18char version of the ID. I've created a formula field ApplicationId__c using CASESAFEID(Application__c), yet it refuses to return the 18 char id in the merge field, and returns the 15 char version instead. I'm also doing the same for the actual merge record's id, which *does* return the 18char id. Is this an issue with the template merge fields? Why can't I get the 18char version? I've also tried creating the formula using CASESAFEID(Application__r.Id), but get the same result.

Does the formula for lookup ids not work with a Lightning Email Template? Does it only work for the actual merge record's Id?

These are the formula fields:

[image] [image]

This is the Lightning Email Template body:

[image]

This is the email I receive:

[image]

And the debug log:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This formula replaces the 15-character ID with the 18-character, case-insensitive ID.

CASESAFEID('A01xx000003DHur') returns A01xx000003DHur. The ID isn’t valid because it begins with a capital letter.

CASESAFEID('001xx000003DHur') returns something like 001xx000003DHurAAG because the ID passed in is valid

this may be why youre getting a 15 char back. Can you try changing "Application__c" to "Application.Id"/"Id" ?

Comment: @Geo the Id doesn't begin with a capital letter, as you can see, and I did try using Application__r.Id as well, which made no difference.